# Php data missing

Tags: php

I'm passing a JSON encoded data from my flash file to php i traced the data output using firebug and i see it's being passed along to php but when i try to return the values back to flash through php i get an empty string can some one expalin why php is behaving like that? here is the code

```
<?php

$data = urldecode(utf8_decode(stripslashes($_REQUEST['data']))); 

$decoded_result = json_decode($data);

print_r($decoded_result);
echo output.'='.$decoded_result;

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you miss a `$` in the `output` variable name?

Come to think of it, *where is the `$output` variable name? is there even one?*

Also, you're invoking `json_decode`, which **decodes JSON into native PHP objects, which don't have an implicit string representation, which will look weird when you do coerce it to a string**, I think you meant to just output the JSON decoded from the `data` `$_REQUEST` hash, there is no use in returning a PHP object to the client.

Maybe you meant to do this:

```
<?php

   $data = urldecode(utf8_decode(stripslashes($_REQUEST['data']))); 

   header('Content-type: application/json');    
   echo $data; //according to your logic, $data already contains JSON, so just output it.

?>
```

Comment: depending on the error setting, if a constant does not exists thats named `output` it will send output to the browser as content, so more than likely he was just sending a string. also I think he wants `print_r`